# Isomorphism between subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $G,H$ be subspaces of a vector space $I$ such that $G \cap H = \{0\}$. Prove that $G + H \cong G\times H$.

I've defined $\phi: G + H \to G\times H$ as $\phi(g + h) = (g,h)$. Showing bijectivity as:

- $\phi(g + h) = \phi(j + k) \implies (g,h) = (j,k) \implies g = j, h = k$, so $g + h = j + k$.
- For all $g,h \in G + H$, we have $\phi(g + h) = (g,h)$ so $\phi$ is onto.

I'm trapped in showing $\phi(hg) = \phi(h)\phi(g)$.

Is my $\phi$ bad?

Comment: In a vector space $V$ a "product" $hg$ for $h,g\in V$ is not defined. Instead, an isomorphism of vector spaces is a bijective linear map.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer to define the map from $G\times H \to G + H$ by
$$
\phi(g,h) = g+h.
$$
Now to show that this is a linear transformation, you need to show that 
$$
\phi[(h,g) + (g', h')] = \phi(g,h) + \phi(g',h')
$$
and
$$
\phi[a(g,h)] = a\phi(g,h)
$$
(for $a\in \mathbb{R})$ or whatever field you are considering.

Showing this is straight forward. The proof that $\phi$ is one-to-one and onto is done just like the function you have. For example, if $\phi(g,h) = \phi(g',h')$, then $g + h = g' + h'$ meaning that $g - g' = h' - h$, but because $G\cap H = \{0\}$, you have $0 = g - g' = h' - h$. I think it would be a good idea to make a reference when you use the facts given.

Answer (score 0):

You have a short exact sequence:
\begin{alignat*}4
0\longrightarrow G\cap H && \longrightarrow G\oplus H &\longrightarrow G+H \longrightarrow 0 \\
x&&\longmapsto (x,x)\\
&&(x,y)&\longmapsto x-y
\end{alignat*}
As $G\cap H=\{0\}$ by hypothesis, the map $\; G\oplus H \longrightarrow G+H $ is an isomorphism.